# MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE is not changing version string in Ubuntu 18.04 with nouveau

Tags: opengl

I am trying to override the detected opengl implementation version (a fix for Dying Light on Steam). From my understanding of opengl, i should be able to set what version it is reported as via the MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE variable.

```
$ glxinfo | grep 'version string'
OpenGL version string: 3.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.0.8

$ MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 glxinfo | egrep 'OpenGL version string'
OpenGL version string: 3.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
```

How can I get gl to report as "3.3" and not the rest of it? I have tried exporting the variable too.

Background: The Dying Light game checks for the version of gl, when I try run it, it crashes:

```
Detected OpenGL Version: 3.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
Required OpenGL version: 3.3
Please update your display driver.
```

There's a few posts here and on the steam site that suggest using the variable, but the compat check still fails

Comment: It already does report as 3.3. "and not the rest of it?"You can't change that, and why would you want to?

Comment: The Dying Light developers are using the gl version call to validate the version of opengl, so to run the game, i want to change the version string via the variable. Detected OpenGL Version: 3.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.0.8

Comment: And you can change the reported GL version via that environment variable. So what is the issue here?

Comment: derhass - i have posted the error message. gl is reporting the "compat" string.

Comment: Do you want it to report a core profile?  If so try `MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3FC`.

Comment: core doesn't work, it segfaults much earlier on in the loading process.

Answer (score 0):

MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.6 MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=460

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.